# Why doesn't font size in table cells behave correctly if text gets long?

Tags: html, css

I have problems with the css, espacially with the font sizes, inside a table. Each cell should have the same font size with `td { font-size: 1.5rem; }` but the cells on the left side of the table have a smaller font size than the cells on the right side **if the text inside the right cell gets to long.**

This problem only occurs when visiting the website on a mobile client.

**CSS:**

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

@media (hover: none) {
    html {
        font-size: 125%;
    }
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

table.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

td {
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

td > b {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

td.wordbreak {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <table class="fullwidth">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 1</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">Content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 2</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">Content 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 3</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">Content 3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 4</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">
                            Content 4
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 5</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">Content 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 6</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">Content 6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 7</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">
                            This is a very long text which leads to css problems. This is a very long text which leads to css problems. This is a very long text which leads to css problems. This is a very long text which leads to css problems. This is a very long text which leads to css problems. This is a very long text which leads to css problems.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title 8</b></td>
                        <td class="wordbreak">Content 8</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my opinion all cells should have the same font size with this code but however the left cells have a smaller font size **if the text inside the right cell gets to long.**

[image: css problems with file size]

Do you know a solution for this?

**EDIT 1**

I think the problem is somewhere in this code snippet:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
@media (hover: none) {
    html {
        /* THIS IS PROBLEMATIC */
        font-size: 125%;
    }
}
```

When I remove the line with the comment, the font size inside the table cells is tiny but at least all the same.

**EDIT 2**

It seems that the css code `table { table-layout: fixed; }` fixed the prolem.

Answer (score 0):

Use table headers, combine your CSS and drop the bold. This way if you wish to style the headers differently it's easy.

```
<tr>
     <th>Title 1</th>
     <td>Content</td>
</tr>
```

css:

```
td, th {
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    word-break: break-word;
}

th {
  word-break: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this way the code is easier to read. But unfortunately the problem with the font size is still there like in my picture. The text inside `<td></td>` is bigger than the text inside `<th></th>`. I don't know where my fault could be.

Comment: Use the browser DOM inspector on the element to help you find the offending style. There may be some *!important* baloney in your attached stylesheet.

Comment: I use the DOM inspector all the time, every `td` or `th` has the `font-size: 1.5rem;` and i have no `!important` in the css. The problem with the different font sizes only occurs when the text in the right cells gets too long.